# shouldReceiveTouch not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to exclude a subview from my TapGestureRecognizer. 
It has been created in sotryboard, the delegate is connected to the controller.

In my ViewControler I have the GestureRecognizerDelegate protocol and I ve set my gesture.delegate = self.

Though the shouldReceiveTouch Gesturerecognizer function is not calling, any idea ?

Here is somne of the code :

```
class DetailedPostViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {


let circularLike = CircularLike(frame: CGRectZero)

@IBOutlet var gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    gesture.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(circularLike)
    circularLike.frame = self.view.bounds

    }


func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(circularLike){
        return false
    }
    return true
    }

@IBAction func UserTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    if fromUser {
     dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("userPage", sender: nil)
    }
    }



@IBAction func hideUnhide(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if hide {
        hide=false
        unhideUi()
    } else {
        hide = true
        hideUi()
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which view added gesture recognizer?

Comment: it s linked to an image (forgot to put it here in the outlets) through storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, In fact, I just had to set my subview userTouchEnabled parameter to false, and it then triggered the ShouldRecieveTouch Function ...